# how to install ros industrial core in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ros, ubuntu-xenial, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to install ros industrial core in ubuntu 16.04 LTS,

when I try to run the command `apt-get install ros-hydro-industrial-desktop`

it appears there is no package available

```
root@ashokkumar-Satellite-C600:~# apt-get install ros-hydro-industrial-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-industrial-desktop
root@ashokkumar-Satellite-C600:~#
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250616/how-to-install-ros-industrial-core-in-ubuntu-16.04?/) by [ashok](https://answers.ros.org/users/28874/ashok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> when I try to run the command `apt-get install ros-hydro-industrial-desktop` it appears there is no package available

The Hydro packages are not available on Kinetic, no.

There is in fact no release of `industrial_desktop` for Kinetic. The only way to use the industrial packages would be to build them from source in a catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashok](https://answers.ros.org/users/28874/ashok/) on 2016-12-22**:
How to use Industrial packages from source in a catkin workspace. an tutorial or examples

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-22**:
Have you completed the regular ROS tutorials?